# Running hudi-cli through bash

Tags: bash, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-hudi

I am trying to automate the savepoint and rollback features of Hudi through hudi-cli in a shell script.

The hudi-cli seems to be an interactive terminal.

I am having the below statement in my bash script:

```
hudi-cli "connect --path s3://test_table;commits show --desc True --limit 1;"
```

I want to get the latest commit in bash script and fire next command as savepoint.

But the problem is, as hudi-cli runs in its own shell which internally uses spark, I am not able to get the output in a variable in bash script. Although I am able to see the variable on command prompt (stdout) The lines printed in the console seem to be from Java code which is internally called by hudi-cli.

How can I achieve the above scenario with a shell script?

PS: I have tried below but it does not give the latest commit

```
read -r output <<< "$(hudi-cli 'connect --path s3://test_table;commits show --desc True --limit 1')"
```

When I do echo $output I get a blank response. Nothing is printed.

However, in terminal I see below output and I am interested in "CommitTime" from the table at the end
[image]

My question is how can I get the latest commit time from the subshell output of hudi-cli

Comment: By the way, this is not your problem but `read -r output <<< "$(command)"` should instead be written as `IFS= read -r output < <(command)`, all on one line.

Comment: You still haven't revealed what the actual result is. If the program prints these results to standard output, you should be able to extract the part you want with `grep`, `sed`, or Awk.

Comment: The result on standard output is printed by the subshell hudi-cli which internally spins up multiple programs. When I grep or pipe the output,  I only get this line : "Client jar location not set, please set it in conf/hudi-env.sh" as mentioned in the question

Comment: Well, **is** `CLIENT_JAR` set in `conf/hudi-env.sh` under the directory your tool exists in? Looking at the code in https://github.com/apache/hudi/blob/master/hudi-cli/hudi-cli.sh (first hit when I googled `"Client jar location not set, please set it in conf/hudi-env.sh"`) should help you.

Comment: That is just one of the side effects. That is not the actual problem. Even if I set it, the message will vanish, but my original problem is to get inner subshell messages. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Please fix any issues you know how to fix before asking for help so we don't waste time trying to help you debug things that aren't your actual problem.

Comment: Fixed the issue for client jar location not set, now I am getting the blank response for echo. Edited in the original question.